# 2 I/GDPAndroid(28712): getCpuTemperature valid path:/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp

Tags: flutter, temperature

my flutter Debug Console keep showing this messages.. endlessly, anyone can assist me to solve this matter? i have also disable agora chat Engine.. however the error still maintain..there ??? please assist..

```
I/GDPAndroid(28712): getCpuTemperature valid 
path:/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp

E/libc    (28712): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc    (28712): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
E/libc    (28712): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc    (28712): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it's on my physical phone only with android 5.0

I tried to not to call enable camera by commenting this line in the **_initEngine()**

```
//await _engine.enableVideo();
```

And the message Gone!!
So after that, I realized it's (Camera Permission issue)

##### [Fix] make sure to ask for permission before enabling the camera

Add this line before _engine.enableVideo();

```
await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
```

##### Code:

```
_initEngine() async {
    _engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(RtcEngineContext(config.appId));
    _addListeners();

    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);

    _joinChannel();
  }
```